# KeyPressed event calls other event

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have an OK button on my WinForm.

I would like to give the option to click the OK button also by enter pressing.

Here is my code:

```
void MyFormKeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)

    {
       if (e.KeyChar==13)

          {
            //What have I to do in order to call ButtonOK click event?
          }
    }
```

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call *PerformClick* method:

```
void MyFormKeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == 13)
            {
                ButtonOK.PerformClick(); // <- click ButtonOK
            }
    }
```

But a better solution is to set MyForm's *AcceptButton* property to *ButtonOK*; in this case you don't have to do anything with KeyPress event.

Comment: First thanks for the quick reply. I tried you code above, nothing happens when I press enter on form. Any idea?

Comment: @user3165438 is your button enabled?

Comment: Probably, you should set KeyPreview to true on MyForm

Answer (score 2):

you can set the [Form.AcceptButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of form to your button.

> This property enables you to designate a default action to occur when the user presses the ENTER key in your application. The button assigned to this property must be an IButtonControl that is on the current form or located within a container on the current form.

Example:

your form name is form1 and your button is button1 then

```
 form1.AcceptButton = button1;
```

should do what you want.

or you can use your existing code and call

```
   yourButton.PerformClick();
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can always call the event handler directly as long as you are not interested in sender and EventArgs objects:

```
void MyFormKeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == 13)
            {
                ButtonOK_ClickHandler(null, null);
            }
    }
```

Comment: If you want to call ButtonOK_ClickHandler() you should not pass null values, but ButtonOK as the first argument and EventArgs.Empty as the second: ButtonOK_ClickHandler(ButtonOK, EventArgs.Empty);

Comment: You need to pass those values only if you use them and on ok button there is a very rear use case for them

Answer (score 1):

```
void MyFormKeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == 13)
        {
            OkButton_Click(null, null);
           // or you can use OkButton.PerformClick();
        }
}
```